# Application Overview

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have recently upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10 and am enjoying using the new Applications Overview. One thing is annoying me though, there is no icon available for the gnome-terminal. It can be found via the searchbox but cannot be found among the listed apps so there is no way to have it on my first page. There are XTerm and UXTerm icons but no gnome-terminal. This is a shame because it is my most used application.

Comment: Well seen! Indeed, I also do not see it in the application overview, even though I have pinned Gnome Terminal to the dash.

Comment: Yes, I too have it in the dash but not in the app. overview.

Comment: Found it. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is there. Only is it hidden in the group "Utilities", second page of icons.

The Gnome Shell application overview is now, since Ubuntu 20.10, organized fully manually. You can drag it out of the group (as in Ubuntu 20.04), but new is that you can place it anywhere you want among the icons, including in the top row of the first page.

For completeness, you may reset your Application overview to an alphabetical list with default groups by issuing the following command in the terminal or in a run dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>):

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout
```